# Передать значение массива в переменную yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Как передать значения массива из БД в переменную?
Хочу сделать управляемое меню для администратора.
На frontend в layouts/main меню прописывается вот тут

```
$menuItems = [
    ['label' => $item1, 'url' => [$item2]],
];
```

Делаю запрос в БД для получения данных   `$query = Menu::find()->all();`
Пытаюсь вывести

```
foreach ($query as $index => $array) {
    $menuItems = [
        ['label' => $item1, 'url' => [$item2]],
    ];
}
```

Но выводит только последнее значение в БД.
Пытался передать значение массивом, как -то так, ошибка

```
$item1 = [];
$item2 = [];
$query = Menu::find()->all();
foreach ($query as $index => $array) {

    $item1[$index]['label'] = $array['text'];
    $item2[$index]['url'] = $array['url'];
}

$menuItems = [
    ['label' => $item1, 'url' => [$item2]],
];
```

А как правильно написать??
В дебагере видно, что параметры передаются

> in C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\path\frontend\views\layouts\main.php at line 72 – yii\base\Widget::widget(['options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'], 'items' => [['label' => [['label' => 'Альбом'], ['label' => 'Про університет'], ['label' => 'Контаксти']], 'url' => [[['url' => 'category/'], ['url' => '/about'], ['url' => '/contact']]]], '

Но ошибка

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: Напишите чётко и доступно, что вы получаете из базы, а потом не менее доступно что вам нужно из этого получить, сейчас у вас видно только ваш код, но из него не очень понятна суть манипуляций

Comment: Вот скрин базы http://c2n.me/3AnGfcN Из нее, мы получаем список text - названия ссылки меню, и сами ссылки - url. Нужно эти параметры записать в $menuItems. По стандарту оно записывается так - ['label' => 'Название', 'url' => ['Ссылка']]. Вопрос как записать в лейбл и урл данные из БД ?

Comment: ага, и что вам нужно получить, какой вид должен быть у меню?

Comment: http://c2n.me/3AnHqku Вот такое меню, где вместо Текст1, Текст2 - данные из БД

Comment: вообще нет проблем :) это же стандартный вывод данных в Yii2

Comment: у меня как-то есть. каким образом сделать можно?

Comment: чтобы меню можно было транслировать на все страницы, вам нужно сделать виджет для этого меню, а в нём уже сделать вьюху, которая будет выводить это меню, сейчас ниже подробно распишу

Comment: та звучит как-то накручено. Просто записать никак не выйдет?) Данные то все передает, просто массив организовать надо по другому, я думаю?

Comment: Сделал, сейчас скину как

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаёте в папке `widgets` (если этой папки нет, то нужно её создать в корне сайта) файл `WMenu.php`:

```
<?php
namespace app\widgets;

use app\models\Menu;
use yii\bootstrap\Widget;

class WMenu extends Widget
{
    public function init(){}

    public function run() {
        return $this->render('menu/view', [
            'menuItems' => Menu::find()->all()
        ]);
    }
}
```

Далее в этой же папке создаёте папку 'views' если у вас ещё не было виджетов до этого, и в папке `views` создаёте папку `menu`, в этом папке будет файл `view.php`:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Url;

?>

<ul>
    <?php foreach($menuItems as $item) {
    ?>
        <li><a href="<?= Url::to(['/'.$item->url]); ?>"><?= $item->text ?></a></li>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Далее в файл `layouts/main.php` сверху добавляете:

```
use app\widgets\WMenu;
```

и в нужное место вставляет такой код:

```
<?= WMenu::widget(); ?>
```

Вот и всё, в принципе это стандартный способ добавления виджетов в проект, очень рекомендую его освоить, он ещё не один раз вам пригодится.

Answer (score 0):

UPD Может кому-то будет нужно

Вот такой код вышел

```
//формируем массив для меню
$query = Menu::find()->all();
$menuItems = [];
foreach ($query as $index => $array) {
    $menuItems[$index]['label'] = $array['text'];
    $menuItems[$index]['url'] = $array['url'];
}
echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
    'items' => $menuItems,
]);
```